# Two wheres and One orWhere Laravel Conditions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

i want to search in Lists and get only the results with id, but search in title and seach in description, i dont want title and description i want title or description, but with this way i get all the results with coincidence in description not is limited for the first condition id, regards.

```
public function search_list( Request $request ){

    $id = $request->input("id_search");

    $data = $request->input("search");

    $lists = Lists::where( 'lists.id_user', $id )
                ->where( "title", "like", "%".$data."%" )
                ->orwhere( "description", "like", "%".$data."%" )
                ->paginate( 10 );

    return view( 'user.lists.list_lists' )
                ->with( "lists", $lists )
                ->with( "data", $data );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`where()` closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#parameter-grouping):

```
Lists::where(function ($q) use ($id, $data) {
        $q->where('lists.id_user', $id)
          ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $data . '%');
    })
    ->orwhere('description', 'like', '%' . $data . '%')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that work, i make little modify becase i need the id in both 

$lists = Lists::where(function ($q) use ($id, $data) {
                    $q->where('lists.id_user', $id)
                      ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $data . '%');
                })->orwhere(function ($q) use ($id, $data) {
                    $q->where('lists.id_user', $id)
                      ->where('description', 'like', '%' . $data . '%');
                })->paginate(10);

But you got it :D